# Lenovo Thinkpad T440p - wifi interface not listed

Tags: wireless, networking, thinkpad

I recently purchased a Lenovo Thinkpad T440p, where I installed Ubuntu 13.04, with the following networking options:

- WiFi card Intel Dual Band Wireless 7260AC with Bluetooth 4.0
- 3G/HSPA+ built-in module (Ericsson N5321)

When I run `ifconfig`, I get only `eth0` and `lo` listed.

When I run `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5227 (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b2 (rev 83)
```

Here is the output of `uname -a`

```
Linux flo-ThinkPad-T440p 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It seems the required firmware is included with Kernel 3.10+ if I understand well what's written at http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi and my kernel is currently at 3.8 something.

Do I need to find the right backport to actually enable WiFi or is there something easier to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, because the post you mention talks about Ubuntu 13.10. My post talks about Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Did you try it and fail? The process is the same.

Comment: I'm about to confirm that upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 (i.e. with kernel 3.11) fixes the issue.

Comment: You will likely still need the firmware.

Comment: Wifi networks are detected now.

Comment: And http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi seems to suggest that kernels 3.10+ ship with the required firmware.

Comment: May we assume you are all set?

Comment: I want to confirm I can access a Wifi network where I actually know the credentials. I can confirm that in a few hours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 (kernel 3.11) solves it.
This confirms http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi list.